# How to set the gradient of a shape when the JFrame is constantly being repainted?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to get an oval to change its gradient's colours every time it reaches a size of 50 or 100:

```
    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

        if(dmt == 100 || dmt == 50) {
            int red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
            Color startColour = new Color(red, green, blue);

            red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
            blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
            green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
            Color endColour = new Color(red, green, blue);

            GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(300, 100, startColour, 150, 150, endColour);
            g2d.setPaint(gradient);
        }
        g2d.fillOval((size-dmt)/2, (size-dmt)/2 - dmt/2, dmt, dmt);
    }
}
```

(dmt is diameter, size is size of window that comes up)

I set 2 random colours for the gradients I want to use for a circle, but I want it to change only when the circle reaches either size 100 or 50 (it is constantly growing and shrinking to these sizes), but since I repaint everything white every time it runs, you can never see it except when its size is exactly 50 or 100. How do I make it always that colour, until it has to change?

Comment: Could this help? http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/ColorGradient.java

Answer (score 2):

> How do I make it always that colour, until it has to change?

Somewhere you must have a method that changes the "dmt" variable. This method should be responsible for changing the properties of your class. So in addition to the `dmt` variable you should also have a `startColor` and `endColor` variables.

Then the code should be something like:

```
public void setDMT(...);
{
    if (dmt == 50 || dmt == 100)
    {
        startColor = ???
        endColor = ???
    }
}
```

When you create the class you would also need to set the startColor/endColor to a default value.

Then in the paintComponent() method you simply use these two varaibles:

```
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.setColor(Color.white);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

    GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(300, 100, startColour, 150, 150, endColour);
    g2d.setPaint(gradient);

    g2d.fillOval((size-dmt)/2, (size-dmt)/2 - dmt/2, dmt, dmt);
```